# Generating Paypal Signature, 'X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION' in Ruby

Tags: ruby, paypal, signature

Is there any library in Ruby that generates the Signature, `'X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION'` header that is required to make calls on behalf of the account holder who has authorized us through the paypal Permissions API.
I am done with the permissions flow and get the required access token, tokenSecret. I feel I am generating the signature incorrectly as all my calls with the the generated 'X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION' fail. They give the following errors:
**For NVP call I get:**
`You do not have permissions to make this API call`

**And for the GetBasicPersonalData call I get:**
`Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.`

Has anyone gone through this in Ruby? What is best way to generate signature. Paypal has just provided some SDK in Paypal, Java, but not the algorithm to generate signature.

Thanks,
Nilesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the PayPal Permissions gem.

https://github.com/moshbit/paypal_permissions

Specifically lib/paypal_permissions/x_pp_authorization.rb
require 'cgi'
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

```
class Hash
  def to_paypal_permissions_query
    collect do |key, value|
      "#{key}=#{value}"
    end.sort * '&'
  end
end

module ActiveMerchant #:nodoc:
  module Billing #:nodoc:
    module XPPAuthorization
      public
      def x_pp_authorization_header url, api_user_id, api_password, access_token, access_token_verifier
        timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
        signature = x_pp_authorization_signature url, api_user_id, api_password, timestamp, access_token, access_token_verifier
        { 'X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION' => "token=#{access_token},signature=#{signature},timestamp=#{timestamp}" }
      end

      public
      def x_pp_authorization_signature url, api_user_id, api_password, timestamp, access_token, access_token_verifier
        # no query params, but if there were, this is where they'd go
        query_params = {}
        key = [
          paypal_encode(api_password),
          paypal_encode(access_token_verifier),
        ].join("&")

        params = query_params.dup.merge({
          "oauth_consumer_key" => api_user_id,
          "oauth_version" => "1.0",
          "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1",
          "oauth_token" => access_token,
          "oauth_timestamp" => timestamp,
        })
        sorted_query_string = params.to_paypal_permissions_query

        base = [
          "POST",
          paypal_encode(url),
          paypal_encode(sorted_query_string)
        ].join("&")
        base = base.gsub /%([0-9A-F])([0-9A-F])/ do
          "%#{$1.downcase}#{$2.downcase}"  # hack to match PayPal Java SDK bit for bit
        end

        digest = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha1', key, base)
        Base64.encode64(digest).chomp
      end

      # The PayPalURLEncoder java class percent encodes everything other than 'a-zA-Z0-9 _'.
      # Then it converts ' ' to '+'.
      # Ruby's CGI.encode takes care of the ' ' and '*' to satisfy PayPal
      # (but beware, URI.encode percent encodes spaces, and does nothing with '*').
      # Finally, CGI.encode does not encode '.-', which we need to do here.
      def paypal_encode str
        s = str.dup
        CGI.escape(s).gsub('.', '%2E').gsub('-', '%2D')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Sample parameters:

```
url = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/GetBasicPersonalData'
api_user_id = 'caller_1234567890_biz_api1.yourdomain.com'
api_password = '1234567890'
access_token = 'YJGjMOmTUqVPlKOd1234567890-jdQV3eWCOLuCQOyDK1234567890'
access_token_verifier = 'PgUjnwsMhuuUuZlPU1234567890'
```

Answer (score 2):

[The X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION header [is] generated with URL "https://svcs.paypal.com/Permissions/GetBasicPersonalData".](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Permissions.pdf) (see page 23, and chapter 7, at the link)

NVP stating "You do not have permissions to make this API call" means your API credentials are correct, just that your account does not have permission for the particular API you are trying to call. Something between the two calls you are submitting is not using the same API credentials.

> **For NVP call I get:**

*What NVP call?*

> TransactionSearch (see comments below)

Also, if you haven't already done so, you will want to use the sandbox APP-ID for testing in the sandbox, and you will need to apply for an app-id with Developer Technical Services (DTS) at PayPal to get an App-ID for live.

**EDIT:**

To use the TransactionSearch API, all you should be submitting is below. You do not need to specify any extra headers.

```
USER=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PWD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SIGNATURE=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
METHOD=TransactionSearch
VERSION=86.0
STARTDATE=2009-10-11T00:00:00Z
TRANSACTIONID=1234567890
//And for submitting API calls on bob's behalf, if his PayPal email was bob@bob.com:
SUBJECT=bob@bob.com
```

Comment: thanks @SgtPooki. I do have the permissions, I am bale to successfully complete the permissions flow. Yes, I am on Sandbox and using the Sandbox APP-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T
The NVP call that I make is 'TransactionSearch' & have also got the required permissions for it. I feel I get the "You do not have permissions to make this API call" even though I have the permissions, because I making making some mistake in generating signature, 'X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION' header. So was looking for some ruby sample that does it correctly or some way to know whether its correctly generated.

Comment: @Nilesh, thanks for the recap! TransactionSearch is not part of the Adaptive Payments API, so it does not require the sending of X-PayPal-Authorization. See the edits made above.

Comment: I need to make the TransactionSearch calls on behalf of account holders that have authorized me, so I definitely need the 'X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION' header. And what I am looking for is a ruby library that generates this header.

Comment: @Nilesh, no, you do not. TransactionSearch is not part of the AdaptivePayments API, so no X-PAYPAL blah blah is needed at all, I promise. If you are submitting API calls on behalf of others, you only need to set 'subject=accountholderspaypal@email.com'

Comment: thanks, but where can I find the documentation for this. I ask this coz I haven't read about it anywhere, nor have I seen it implemented in such fashion. Also, to get the 'accountholderspaypal@email.com' I will have to make call to 'GetBasicPersonalData' & I get this as response:
"Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect." I want to get this get without having to ask user for it, to make it a seamless user experience.

Comment: hey I tried your suggestion & it worked. I found the documentation here: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/overview.html

thanks for that, no one ever pointed that out & I missed it as well.

But my problem still remains: 
'to get the 'accountholderspaypal@email.com' I will have to make call to 'GetBasicPersonalData' & I get this as response: "Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect." I want to get this implicitly without having to ask user for it, to make it a seamless user experience.'