# Generating Signatures for the Authentication Header in PHP - Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, oauth

Having recently finished the [process](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsUsing/) of having created the script that retrieves permissions from a account holder I now find that I have to convert the retrieved `access token` and `token secret` (from the `GetAccessToken` response) to the **API signature** in order to create a `X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION` header.

The X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION header contains:

- A timestamp
- The access token from the GetAccessToken response
- A **signature** generated from the following information:

  - Your API username
  - Your API password
  - The access token from the GetAccessToken response
  - The token secret from the GetAccessToken response
  - The endpoint for the PayPal API operation's request, such as https://api.paypal.com/nvp
  - HTTPS delivery method, such as POST
  - Request parameters associated with the request

The problem is I can't find how to generate the signature. There are no guides in PHP ([JAVA](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsUsing/) and [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578895/generating-paypal-signature-x-paypal-authorization-in-ruby)).

I did however note the line in the guide I followed (first link) to retrieve the permissions:

> PayPal provides SDKs that you can use to generate authentication header signatures for Java, PHP, and .NET. When you use the SDK, you will get two values, such as the following:

But what followed was the JAVA guide and I could not find anything amongth Paypal's SDKs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/) actually cuts out the function from their PHP SDK that should do it for you.

```
private function generateAuthString($apiCred, $accessToken, $tokenSecret, $endpoint)
{
$callerUid = $apiCred->getUserName();
$callerPswd = $apiCred->getPassword();
$auth = new AuthSignature();
$response = $auth->genSign($callerUid,$callerPswd,$accessToken,$tokenSecret,'POST',$endpoint);
$authString =
"token=".$accessToken.
",signature=".$response['oauth_signature'].
",timestamp=".$response['oauth_timestamp'];
return $authString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find it. But this will do.